# how to backup the sql file for wordpress in microsoft azure cloud?

Tags: wordpress, azure, azure-sql-database, cloud-hosting, database-backups

i installed a word press blog in Microsoft azure using the image from new ->website >gallery

it was easy but now i want to take a backup of my .sql file of word press i cant see any phpadmin access and the database is automatically created when i used it install from gallery and also when i navigate to sql database in portal i cant find any databases and my website is running fine how is it so ?

how to access the database and download the backup ?

thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not that familiar with WordPress, but my experience tells me that [this would be your best a reliable choice to back up your WordPress database](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-sql-backup/).

As for phpMyAdmin and other stuff - you can always connect to your Azure Website [using FTP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2012/06/19/windows-azure-website-uploading-downloading-files-over-ftp-and-collecting-diagnostics-logs.aspx). You can do whatever you want with the content, once connected with the FTP client of your choice (understand - you can upload your version of phpmyadmin and have it there running for you).

Comment: I have been trying several different backup plugins and nothing seems to work. I don't know if something has changed, but this plugin didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

You can always access MySQL database using the connection string provided on your website's dashboard in Azure management ("View connection strings"). Then you can use program like MySQL Workbench (or perhaps even phpMyAdmin on your local machine) to access the database.

Backing up from MySQL workbench is quick and easy, see e.g.[Making a MySQL database backup with MySQL Workbench](http://community.discountasp.net/showthread.php?t=11972). Remember to also back up files.